# Не отображаются css стиль указанныц в forms.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, виджет

Пытаюсь указать class для поля username,  но оно выводится с кастомными параметрами.

Скриншот страницы входа:
[image: страница входа]

Код этой страницы на Django:

[image: код1]
[image: код2]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.